# How to dynamically fetch some html file and use it to create content of a DIV with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Say,how to implement these three steps:

1.fetch a html source from server side

2.use the above source to create a DIV

3.append it to `<body>` Element

Comment: Because for those questions,there is no perfect answer in 3 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('<div></div>').load("/url/to/load.html").appendTo('body');
```

will create a div on the fly then make an ajax call (this must be a local file here), then append it to your body.

Additionnaly you can give your div more attributes :

```
$('<div class="cssname"><span>hello</span></div>')
```

Plus, you can also specifies a certain div of your page to load :

```
$('<div></div>').load("/url/to/load.html #onlythis .block")
```

There's no limit and keep in mind that if you want to create something that don't exist in your page, just do :

```
$('<element></element>')
```

and don't forget to append it

HF !

Comment: @Russ, agreed. Let's see if Shore actually *accepts* it... =/

Comment: How to directly append html to body?

Comment: I mean is this doable:$.load("/url/to/load.html").appendTo('body');

Comment: i don't know, just try it ! This will work i think.

Also $('body').load('...'); will work but replacing all your code in body (so this is useless to do it in ajax !)

$('<div></div>').load("/url/to/load.html").appendTo('body');

is a better solution, since you html will be wrapped in a single <div>. And it's faster to append only one big <div> for jquery than to append multiple <div>'s <h1>'s etc...

Comment: At last,I need to give the DIV container a ID,so,before appending it,need to check if it's already in DOM,if so,just use it.How ?

Comment: var myDiv = $('#divId');
if (myDiv[0])
{
myDiv.load("/url/to/load.html").appendTo('body');
}
else
{
myDiv = $('<div id="divId"></div>').load("/url/to/load.html").appendTo('body');
}

Comment: Bad news!$.load("Views/chatBox.html").appendTo('body') is not working!TypeError: $.load is not a function

Comment: @Shore - you would need to use $.get for that and append the result to body. There is no $.load , as the load command expects an HTML element to append the result into. http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Answer (score 0):

add a  with class name to end of body say "append" with nothing in it.

then

```
$('.append').load('url of content');
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: That's the element's classname to which jQuery will append the loaded file.

Comment: I don't want to put it in html before using it,how to create the element on the fly?